# PDF not drawn correctly on canvas, in Safari

Tags: html5-canvas, safari

I'm trying to select a certain are of an image and then display that portion inside a canvas.
In order to see what's actually happening, I've reduced the code to a simple snippet:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>

(...)

imageObj.onload = function() {
        // draw cropped image
        var sourceX = 0;
        var sourceY = 0;
        var sourceWidth = 200;
        var sourceHeight = 200;
        var destX = 0;
        var destY = 0;
        var destWidth = 200;
        var destHeight = 200;

        context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
};
```

If I use an actual image, everything works as expected (you can see a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q3fa/2/)).

[image]

In order to get a higher text quality, I use a Safari feature that lets me give an image tag a pdf source. However, when I try to draw the same part on a canvas, I get a different area rendered, as you can also see [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q3fa/3/) (Safari is required)

[image]

The PDF is actually the original JPG image exported as a PDF file (with Mac's Preview) so the size itss the same. I've had this problem with different PDF files, from different sources, so this is not a problem caused by the way I created the PDFS.
The only change I do in the code is to switch the extension, jpg to pdf.

Drawing the fullsize image on a canvas works just fine, both versions are rendered the same way so its not like Safari cannot draw a PDF correctly on a canvas period.

Did anyone else ran into this problem? Is there anything I could do?